# Встраивание видео с Youtube с автовоспроизведением?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

Есть необходимость встроить видео с `YouTube` на сайт с автоматическим вопроизведением.

[В документации написано](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en#zippy=%2Cturn-on-privacy-enhanced-mode%2Cmake-an-embedded-video-play-automatically) просто добавь `?autoplay=1` и атрибут `allow="autoplay"` и если оно не 18+ будет счастье.
Но это не работает... (*При чем даже их пример с объяснения не работает). На других [форумах](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405242/how-can-i-autoplay-a-video-using-the-new-embed-code-style-for-youtube) рекомендуют убирать звук, и тогда всё будет стартовать. Но тоже что-то не помогает.

Есть ли решение данной проблемы ?

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kJQP7kiw5Fk?autoplay=1&muted=1"  allow="autoplay"
    allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: какая конкретно проблема со встраиванием? Ошибка? Видео не загружается? Видео не запускается? У некоторых видео/каналов стоит запрет на встраивание

Comment: Видео встраиваеться. Проблема в автовоспроизведении. Как автоматом стартовать видео? Подойдет любое решение. Черех `GET` параметр, через `API`, через скрипт на событие... задача в том что б оно ощущалось как автоматическое воспроизведение.  Устроит даже вариант старт по ховеру.

Comment: любое видео не запускается?

Comment: Я опробовал на 3-х примерах. У меня не запустилось. Мне вообще-то желательно определенное видео. Конечно могу создать канал... залить на него видео... получить страйк от правообладателя за повтор контента, но поскольку у меня задача не получить прибиль с контента, а дать просматривать, то это не критично. Просто автоматом запускать.

Comment: добавь ссылку на видео которое хотел показывать. Заработал пример с параметрами `autoplay=1&muted=1`

Comment: Это пока не очень принципиально какой клип.  К примеру https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJQP7kiw5Fk

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151980/discussion-between-grundy-and-blackstar1991).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50272974/13754729

Comment: ```<iframe
    id="existing-iframe-example"
    width="640" height="360"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7dYKr4zHi78?autoplay=1&mute=1&enablejsapi=1"
    frameborder="0"
    style="border: solid 4px #37474F"
></iframe>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50272974/13754729)

не работает обычная вставка видео с апреля 2018 года, поскольку Google решил предоставить пользователям больший контроль над воспроизведением. Вам просто нужно добавить &mute=1 в вашу адресную строку (как вы и сказали) и правильно @Grundy подметил, что на некотрые видео стоит запрет.

```html
<iframe id="existing-iframe-example" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7dYKr4zHi78?autoplay=1&mute=1&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" style="border: solid 4px #37474F"></iframe>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, может ещё подскажете, где именно можно узнать как убрать этот запрет ?  * Если дубль видео на youtube надо сделать ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 вы ссылку откуда берете  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0svwf.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzOGp.png

Comment: а запрет, если пользователь поставил, то он только сам может убрать в настройках канала youtube