Как сделать autoplay youtube видео в модальном окне на javascript?
Как сделать autoplay youtube видео в модальном окне при открытии и останавливать видео при закрытии на javascript
Получилось найти решение только на остановку видео
Вот мой код


document.querySelectorAll('.video-btn').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      document.querySelectorAll('.video').forEach(item => {
          item.classList.add('video-active');
      })
  })
})
let videoClose = document.querySelectorAll('.video-close');
let video = document.querySelectorAll('.video');
videoClose.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      video.forEach(item => {
          item.classList.remove('video-active');

      })
  })
})

const videoStop = document.querySelector('.video-close');
if (videoStop) {
  videoStop.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let iframe = document.querySelector('.video iframe');
    iframe.src = iframe.src;
  });
}
.video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: .3s all;
    &__wrap {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        min-height: 100vh;
        min-width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        z-index: 2000;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
    &-close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;
        right: 31px;
        z-index: 20000;
        width: 20px;
    }
}
.video-active {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
<div class="video">
        <iframe class="video__wrap" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Cmdjpu3E_o?si=hC1-OTh-6FuqOq7p&amp;controls=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <img class="video-close" src="img/close.svg" alt="close">
</div>




может поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1571165/%d0%92%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-%d1%81-youtube-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc/1571612#1571612
